# only keep A-Z 0-9 and remove other characters from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

i am trying to verify strings to make valid urls our of them

i need to only keep A-Z 0-9 and remove other characters from string using **javascript** or **jquery**

for example :

**Belleâ€™s Restaurant**

i need to convert it to :

**Belle-s-Restaurant**

so characters â€™s removed and only A-Z a-z 0-9 are kept

thanks

Comment: You have read the string in the wrong encoding. If you decode it as UTF-8, you can see that the character is U+2019 which is the character `’`. Whilst this doesn't affect the solution here as UTF-8 guarantees that ASCII codes don't appear in multibyte codes, I think you should still update your code to use the correct text encoding. If you make this error here, someone could copy your code and make the same error elsewhere where it will show to your clients.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By adding our `.cleanup()` method to the String object itself, you can then cleanup any string in Javascript simply by calling a local method, like this:

```
# Attaching our method to the String Object
String.prototype.cleanup = function() {
   return this.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "-");
}

# Using our new .cleanup() method
var clean = "Hello World".cleanup(); // "hello-world"
```

Because there is a plus sign at the end of the regular expression it matches one *or more* characters. Thus, the output will always have one `'-'` for each series of one or more non-alphanumeric characters:

```
# An example to demonstrate the effect of the plus sign in the regular expression above
var foo = "  Hello   World    . . .     ".cleanup(); // "-hello-world-"
```

Without the plus sign the result would be `"--hello-world--------------"` for the last example.

Comment: If toLowerCase, why A-Z?

Answer (score 8):

Or this if you wanted to put dashes in the place of other chars:

```
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-');
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the string is kept in a variable called `BizName`:

```
BizName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-');
```

`BizName` should now only involve the characters requested.