# Remove some characters from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

The characters in my string need to match this expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-:]+$,
```

I want to remove every character that does not match the expression above (also spaces).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [only keep A-Z 0-9 and remove other characters from string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983767/only-keep-a-z-0-9-and-remove-other-characters-from-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace is your friend here:

```
var str="asfafasf@##f2f32f";
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-:]/g,"") //output: asfafasff2f32f
```

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` can be simplified to `\w` aka `str.replace(/[^\w\-:]/g,'')`